# Asynchronous communication in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-networking, apache-mina

I am trying to integrate apacahe Mina in android.

Can we persist objects using AsyncTask & pass to UI or another class for further use?

for example

```
public class NetworkConnect extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... param) {

                 Protocol p = new Protocol(); //here I m making connection with echo server
                 //Now I want that session in UI to send messages to echo Server
        }
}
```

I want to use this 'p' instance in other class(Like UI) and using this 'p' instance  call to attributes of Protocol class.
How to do that? or Is there any alternative solution?
Basically 'Protocol' class should run parallel to UI thread and based on events both should be able to communicate with each other.

Suppose there is echo server...then when someone enter input to 'Input' edittext and hit 'send' button, echoServer will give me back this 'input' again. 
Now my problem is that using AsyncTask I am able to connect server, But I am unable to using same session in UI. So I can't send data to server.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You just need to store a reference to that object in a field (rather than a local variable like you showed), and provide methods to use it as needed.  If it needs to always run on a background thread, then those methods can start an AsyncTask.

Comment: It is solved. I did same thing though. Though really thanx for taking interest